# Differences between GenericSuperclass in Java vs C#

Tags: java, c#, .net-core

Java code

```
public abstract class A<T extends AA> extends B
{
    public A()
    {
        Type type = this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass();

        ParameterizedType parametrizedType = (ParameterizedType) type;
        Type[] fieldArgTypes = parametrizedType.getActualTypeArguments();
        parameterType = (Class<T>) fieldArgTypes[0];
    }
 }
```

In C# .NET CORE I wrote this:

```
public abstract class A<T> : B where T: class
{        
    public A()
    {
        Type type = GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition();
        parameterType = type.GenericTypeArguments[0];
    }
}
```

But when I run program I've got error: `This operation is only valid on generic types.` And I have no idea how to fix this. I want to achieve the same what is in Java code.

Comment: `GetType()` should be called on a type instance. does this line compiles `GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition();`?

Comment: @Rahul and in Java code do you see type? I need write the same in C#. Yes

Comment: Not clear what you want to do here, but are you looking for `this.GetType().GetGenericArguments()`?

Comment: @DavidG I want force my c# program to do the same what JAVA

Comment: Well I don't do Java so I have no idea what you're trying to do

Comment: What is the expected output of what you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I red Java documentation about `this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass();` and it has nothing to do with generics whatsoever, the C# Code could be `GetType().GetTypeInfo().BaseType`. And for now works excellent.